# Python, get random records from dataframe but with levels of priority on different columns unique values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 4 columns:  County, Salesperson, Part Number, and $Total.  There can be any number of rows, from tens of thousands to 2 to none.

I'd like to be able to give python a number (let's assume I'm setting with an inputbox value) for the total number of rows in my new randomized report.  However, I would like Python to "randomly" pull those records BUT with giving 3 different fields a tiered priority for maximizing the UNIQUE values.  I want to make sure that, up to the number of records I've specified (let's use 5 as an example), Python will:

1. Get 5 records where all 5 values in County are unique, all 5 values in Salesperson are unique, all 5 values in Partnumber are unique.  If that's not possible, then:
2. 5 records where all 5 County values are unique, all 5 values in Salesperson are unique, and as many as possible values are unique in Partnumber.  If THAT's not possible, then:
3. 5 records where all 5 County values are unique, as many as possible are unique in Salesperson, and given those two columns, as many values as possible are unique in Partnumber.  If THAT's not possible, then:
4. 5 records where as many as possible are unique in County, then as many as possible unique in Salesperson, then as many as possible unique in Partnumber

Note that just trying to use unique key across all 3 fields could very well give me lots of repeated values as long as one of the columns has unique values.  For instance, with this dataframe, if I wanted 5 records pulled that have unique values using all 3 columns as combined key:

```
County      SalesPerson PartNum     $Total
Roberts     Marcus      2A          300
Lewis       James       100A        400
Roberts     Ruby        5Z          100
Midland     Marcus      10B         50
Lewis       Marcus      5E          400
Middlesex   Marcus      1W          25
Fannin      Marcus      10E         45
```

Python might give me this:

```
County      SalesPerson PartNum     $Total
Roberts     Ruby        5Z      100
Midland     Marcus      10B     50
Lewis       Marcus      5E      400
Middlesex   Marcus      1W      25
Fannin      Marcus      10E     45
```

That has 5 unique records given all 3 columns as a whole since all the part numbers are different, but I have lots of duplicate salesperson values, and didn't get a record with James.  In the original dataframe, County has 5 unique values, so my resulting records should have all 5 unique County names. I should have all 3 Salesperson values also, but not the Roberts county record for Marcus (since Ruby is in only one record, the algorithm should see that it can still get 5 unique values for County and also get all 3 salespeople as long as it gets the Ruby record and a NON-Roberts county record for Marcus).  So my output SHOULD be:

```
County      SalesPerson PartNum     $Total
Lewis       James       100A        400
Roberts     Ruby        5Z          100
Midland     Marcus      10B         50
Middlesex   Marcus      1W          25
Fannin      Marcus      10E         45
```

Now there's this dataframe, and let's say I give "5" again:

```
County      SalesPerson PartNum     $Total
Roberts     Marcus      2A          300
Lewis       James       100A        400
Middlesex   Ruby        5Z          100
Middlesex   Marcus      1W          50
Middlesex   James       100A        400
Middlesex   Marcus      2X          25
Fannin      Marcus      10E         45
```

There are only 4 unique county values, so one of them will be represented twice in my report.  So, given that Python has already made sure to max out possible unique values in County, it must now max out unique in Salesperson.  So of my 5 needed records, it will get 2 Middlesex County records, and focus on making sure we get as many unique Salesperson values as possible.  So Ruby will definitely be one of them, as she has only one record and we've already fulfilled max number of unique County.  For the OTHER Middlesex record, python would NOT pick the James option, because that would give me a duplicate Partnumber when it's possible to get a different Partnumber and having already maxed out unique County AND unique Salesperson; so I would get either one of the Middlesex Marcus records (one with Partnumber 1W OR 2X):

```
County      SalesPerson PartNum     $Total
Roberts     Marcus      2A          300
Lewis       James       100A        400
Middlesex   Ruby        5Z          100
Middlesex   Marcus      1W          50
Fannin      Marcus      10E         45
```

One thing that occurred to me was making 3 lists of unique values from each of the three columns, then interating through each list in order of priority (get first value of County list, make a new dataset of all records in original dataframe where County matches that value, then get first value of my Salesperson unique list, find all rows of my NEW data set where Salesperson is that value, turn that into a smaller subset, then search THAT for where Partnumber is the first Partnumber value from my list, then randomly get a record where all that was successful, then starting over with all my searched values removed the respective lists, and doing all of THAT until i've iterated through my specified number (5 in these cases).  But I think that breaks whenever I have fewer unique values than my specified number in any of my lists, also doesn't take into account prioritizing one column over the other when a higher priority one doesn't have as many unique values as my specified number, and also doesn't seem very pythonic.

Any help on this would be very much appreciated, I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it and am not super familiar with python.  I hope my descriptions are clear, please let me know if I need to clarify further.  And again sorry about the length of this, it was difficult for me to clearly communicate this briefly.

Comment: Do you have any code you have tried?

Comment: I apologize, I don't have code I tried, because even thinking of what I potentially could figure out to do it wouldn't address my needs (e.g. the  unique concatenated list with continuously reduced dataframes idea).  I'd welcome even just a textual idea of how to achieve this using python, then I could try to figure out how to achieve that idea in actual code, as long as it's something python is capable of